# How to show my real IP address even VPN or open gate

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ip

I wanna to create a project that will allow to show my real IP address even I changed my IP throw any VPN or gate public.

So may required one textbox which will show my IP and one button.

Answer (score 0):

Make your program to store the IP of the user at all times, if the IP changes you know it uses an VPN which means that the old IP is the "old one" and could then be written to the textbox.

Kind regards,

Comment: This of course means that it won't detect the old IP if the program is started after the initial IP change

Comment: For Now I din't Got Solution Yet :(

Comment: The thing is that Stackoverflow is for code-help, not a place to get work done for you. I gave you a written solution, try it out with your current coding knowledge and come back if you need help :)